# How to unblock wifi at boot?

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, networkmanager, network-interface

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Each time my laptop boots, wifi is off (`rfkill` list states that Wlan0 is Soft blocked).

Obviously, I can unblock it (thanks to the GUI, or command `rfkill unblock wifi` or `rfkill unblock wlan`).

How to to get unblocked wifi at boot?

Side note: I tried *uninstalling NetworkManager*, and this works for unblocking wlan, but it is not an option because NM is useful elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use script, which is run automatically every time you boot.

Add `rfkill unblock wifi` or `rfkill unblock wlan` to `/etc/rc.local`

To do that in Ubuntu 14.04 use gedit text editor (or your favourite one):

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```